# Strange bitwise operation on a 16-bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

i'm looking at a c source file and i found this macro:

```
#define random ( (float) rand() / (float) ((1 << 31) -1) )
```

while in standard ANSI C rand() returns an integer in [0,32767], i really appreciate an help to understand what kind of normalization factor is the denominator, because signed integer are 16 bit and the expression does a 31-bit shift.

Thank you very much for your attention
Best regards

Comment: why do you say signed integer is 16 bits?

Comment: For one, signed integers aren't always 16 bits. It's probably 32 bits in this case.

Comment: The C standard only guarantees that `int`s are AT LEAST 16 bits (they are quite often 32 bits, but they could also be 64 or 48 bits or many other sizes).

Comment: Actually, `rand()` returns an integer in the range `[0, RAND_MAX]`. On my platform `RAND_MAX` is `2147483647`.

Answer (score 2):

`rand` does not return an integer in [0,32767] in "ANSI C".  §7.20.2:

> The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`.

It seems likely that whoever wrote that macro was working on a platform on which `RAND_MAX` was 2147483647.

---

You also seem to be confused about signed integers.  `int` must be *at least* 16 bits wide, but it is often wider.

Comment: In C, `RAND_MAX` is at least `32767`. `RAND_MAX` is *usually* equal to `32767` on systems with 16-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define random ( (float) rand() / (float) ((1 << 31) -1) )
```

in a system with 16-bit `int`, this macro is undefined behavior because of `1 << 31` expression (`1` is of `int` type).

> (C99, 6.5.7p3) "If the value of the right operand is negative **or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand**, the behavior is undefined."